# Generic Type Conversions

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I am trying to convert an object to a generic type.  Here is an example method:

```
void Main()
{
    object something = 4;
    Console.WriteLine(SomeMethod<int>(something));
    Console.WriteLine(SomeMethod<string>(something));
}

public T SomeMethod<T>(object someRandomThing)
{

    T result = Convert.ChangeType(someRandomThing, typeof(T));

    return result;
}
```

This gives this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I have tried several variations to get my result cast as the generic type, but it is not working out each time.

**Is there a way to make this cast?**

NOTE: In my real example I am getting an "object" back from a stored procedure.  The method could call one of several stored procedures, so the result could be a string or a int (or long) depending on which sproc is called.

Comment: You should avoid putting yourself in this position at all possible costs.  If you're calling two procedures, which may return different things, wrap one of them in a method call that changes the type to the type that you want, so that at any given time you know what the *actual* type of your inputs are.

Comment: @Servy - I do that.  The method in question is a protected method of a base abstract class to abstract away the database plumbing.  The Public method is several variations that look like `GetNewWidgetId()` and it calls the protected method.

Comment: Rather than having the abstract method return an object, have it return either a string or an int; require one of the implementations to alter the return value of their DB call to what the method requires it to return.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Convert.ChangeType` returns object so you will need to cast the result back to a `T`

```
T result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(someRandomThing, typeof(T))
```

Comment: I'm sure the OP knows but might want to add a note that you should handle exceptions if the conversion is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(someRandomThing, typeof(T));
```